# Different font color for question status => closed <=

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I stared at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315760/any-memory-usage-paradigm-besides-stack-and-heap-question-refined) ([revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2315760/revisions)) and I even thought **[question refined]** as offical status of the post.

<somebody **[removed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2315760/revisions)** it now, So, I've edited this question to get same effect>

How about official status **[closed]** as

- different font color or
- different font size or
- put the text **[closed]** outside the question link

Or

- put a special tag as suggested in the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40260/different-font-color-for-question-status-closed/40262#40262)

to clarify from those?

Comment: I was actually incorrect. At some point I guess I saw the **[closed]** in the edit field of a question and assumed that was how the Closed system works. I was wrong, and after looking at a few questions I find it does not work this way.

Comment: Ah, ok, I also just trying see some edits, can't find that text.

Comment: screenshot-with-freehand-circles or it didn't happen...  (kidding, it's in the edit history)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90111/change-the-way-a-closed-question-is-marked

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to see it added as a special (non user selectable) tag similar to the `[status-declined]` type tags here on meta.

Not only would that give an immediate visual indication, <del>but it would also have the extra benefit(?) of allowing you to include/exclude `[closed]` questions in searches</del>.

**Edit**: I forgot, but as @waiwai933 pointed out, you can already search for closed questions (`closed:1`)... however I still think the visual indication alone makes it worth implementing.

If you wanted to take the idea further though, you could expand the `[closed]` tag to different tags for each close reason (i.e. `[closed-duplicate]`, `[closed-not-programming]`, `[closed-subjective]`, `[closed-off-topic]`, `[closed-too-local]`, `[migrated-to-meta]`, `[migrated-to-so]`, `[migrated-to-su]`, `[migrated-to-sf]`) then you'd get some potentially useful search abilities since you'd be able to find questions closed for specific reasons... (plus you could find all questions migrated `/questions/tagged/migrated~`, or all questions closed (not migrated) `/questions/tagged/closed~`).

Comment: Good idea. Agree

Comment: And do all kind of cool searches! Like sorting closed questions by votes, etc

Comment: @koper @S.Mark There is the closed:1 boolean operator for search.

Comment: no, overloading tags in this way would just be noise.

Comment: Jeff, How about my original suggestions, instead of tag?

Comment: Notifying @Jeff - just in case you missed @S.Mark's comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old feature request, but I can't disagree. I think putting it maybe to the left would work better like:

> [Closed] [Question Title](/a/252908/238126)

or for duplicates:

> [Duplicate] [Question Title](/a/252908/238126)

would look better in my opinion.