# Take "[" "closed" "]" out of question link when it appears next to question title

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different font color for question status => [closed] <=](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40260/different-font-color-for-question-status-closed)

Take, for example, [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556183/make-c-crash-without-casting). The title line, all linked, reads "Make C++ crash without casting? [closed]".

However, the text "[closed]" isn't part of the title. This is confirmed when you click "edit" and see that the post title field doesn't have "[closed]" in it. The text is just graphical sugar on the question's view page.

I think that putting this text inside the link makes it seem like it's part of the title, and *may* contribute to relative newcomers writing titles like "[jQuery] how do I use this function?", including the topic in the title separate from, and regardless of, wiki tags?

Thoughts?

<sub>(It's telling that I was prohibited from writing "[closed]" in the middle of *this* question's title.)</sub>

Comment: +1, but you have been duplicated with my very old request - possible duplicate of [Different font color for question status => \[closed\] <=](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40260/different-font-color-for-question-status-closed). and this is my last vote left for today.

Comment: Yes, especially with regard to how an official feature sets the wrong example.

Comment: @YOU: Thanks for spending it on me. :)

Comment: This is getting ridiculous now. I'd estimate that over 25% of all new questions on Stack Overflow have clear, non-conversational "tags" leading their titles. Additionally, over the last day or so it suddenly seems to have become _really_ trendy to use greetings and signatures in questions. Can we make advice on the "Ask Question" page more hard-hitting?

Comment: OK. [Seriously.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132745/a-fast-way-to-extract-similar-data-in-array#comment-7213641) Can we have some ground rules in the FAQ?