# Change the way a closed question is marked

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

For example:

- For an MVC architecture, should I prefer Ruby on Rails or PHP [closed]
- Gmail: What is a jQuery selector for incoming mail senders only? How to work with highly compressed and nested CSS in general? [closed]

Better to convert to

- [closed] For an MVC architecture, should I prefer Ruby on Rails or PHP
- [closed] Gmail: What is a jQuery selector for incoming mail senders only? How to work with highly compressed and nested CSS in general?

I should first read the title and sometimes open the question to understand if the question is closed.

I think the `[closed]` mark  should be at the beginning of the title, not in the end, where I won't ever be if the title is long.

Also coloring will be a good improvement (via @Shadow Wizard).

Comment: Are you saying that you'd generally prefer *not* to open closed questions, so you'd rather it be at the beginning where you'll be more likely to notice it?

Comment: I prefer to know if question is closed first and after this make a decision if I want to read it

Comment: Erm, so you prefer not to read the rest of the title if it has the word [closed] at the beginning?  I'd say something about that, but I'm too lazy to write anymore so...zzzzzz

Comment: @Robert Harvey, no I didn't say something about my decision, actually I said, that I want to know it earlier then I read the title. It is okay, I think. But you're too lazy :)

Comment: I can agree that placing it in the beginning makes more sense instead of placing it at the end of a title. At least at most sites (forums etc) you also have leading tags like [updated], [closed], [important]. But it is not a big deal to me.

Comment: I would rather see it marked with different color, like there is different color for questions with zero answers or questions that are in your favorite tags list.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, it will be good as well

Comment: @fl00r: You could start by making a good example and give your question a title from which one can see what your question is about! I had to first open your question to see what it is all about `:-)` (I clicked on it to find out how a question mark could possibly be closed.)

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt, done :)

Comment: @fl00r I think that different wording will improve your question greatly.. for example "Change the way a closed question is marked".

Comment: @fl00r cheers, this already gave you two more votes (except my own) hopefully it will also be handled at some time. :)

Comment: In addition to `[closed]` what about `[migrated]` I also feel that it could be in a inverted color instead of square backets. Like orange for closed, and grey for migrated.

Comment: Yes, and let's take the text "[closed]" out of the link on the question's page. It's misleading, and _may appear_ to some to set a precedent for writing BB-style tags in titles.