# Display "Closed as ..." before the actual question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, closed-questions

Sometimes you open a lengthy question, read through it and then discover "Closed as ..." at the bottom (sometimes only after scrolling) - oops, not something you can answer. Wouldn't it make more sense to display that message before the actual question? Or maybe even in both locations? That's really important information.

**Edit**: Looks like my concern would be solved by [Different font color for question status => closed <=](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40260/different-font-color-for-question-status-closed), thanks to Tim Stone for pointing that out.

Comment: You flagged this as a duplicate and then edited it two minutes later to make it different

Comment: @Michael: Does that invalidate the flag? Heh...

Comment: @Does Well, yes; by "different" I meant "not a duplicate anymore". The other post was about coloring the `[closed]` text somehow; yours is about putting the whole `Closed as` box at the beginning of the question

Comment: @Michael: It is rather about putting *something* visible at the beginning of the question, making [closed] text stand out is a perfect answer to my request (especially if combined with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90111/change-the-way-a-closed-question-is-marked). Btw, my edit didn't change the meaning - only added a note that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're only concerned about *if* the question is closed, and not why...

[image: The title telling you the question is closed]

Comment: I just spent 10 minutes searching for the feature-request that added that; I can't find it anywhere (I did find 19 people asking for `[migrated]` though)

Comment: Our brains tend to ignore text that doesn't stand out. Anyway, duplicates have a message before the question that you will see - questions closed as off-topic or similar don't.

Comment: @Wladimir Duplicates have an extra message because they have extra information -- the list of duplicate posts. The post already says "closed" in two spots; we really don't need three

Comment: @WladimirPalant Well, there is an [existing feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40260) to make the `[closed]` text more distinct from the title itself.

Comment: @Tim Stone: Thank you, didn't find it when I was looking. Flagged my question as a duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I wasn't able to find it either, so I've decided you're crazy and it doesn't exist.